# Run an exe from the run.ps1 of an Azure WebJob

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-webjobs, azureportal

I'm trying to make a deploy in the Azure Portal. Once the deploy is done, it will start with a powershell script which will launch an executable located in the same directory

Content of run.ps1 (the script)

```
& ScrapperProcessor.exe
```

Where "ScrapperProcessor.exe" is the name of the executable.

The parent folder of both "run.ps1" and "ScrapperProcessor.exe" is called "Debug"

I get the following logs:

```
[01/08/2018 06:27:52 > f328c1: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[01/08/2018 06:27:58 > f328c1: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.ps1' with script host - 'PowerShellScriptHost'
[01/08/2018 06:27:58 > f328c1: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ] & : The term 'ScrapperProcessor.exe' is not recognized as the name of a 
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ] cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ] name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\Scr7\xbs0kgzn.2e4\Debug\run.ps1:1 char:3
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ] + & ScrapperProcessor.exe
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ] +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ScrapperProcessor.exe:String) [ 
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ]    ], CommandNotFoundException
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: ERR ]  
[01/08/2018 06:28:07 > f328c1: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: If you want to run the .exe file. You need to  rename it to be `run.exe`first. You can see more details in this document:https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs

Comment: The .exe file is compiled from a visual studio project. I cannot change it's name, otherwise I get an exception at runtime. I also have other .exe files there, but I only intend to run ScrapperProcessor.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to change:

```
& ScrapperProcessor.exe
```

to

```
& .\ScrapperProcessor.exe
```